# Matter waves properties

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

In classical waves, there is always something that is'waving Thus in water waves the water surface moves up and down, in sound waves the air pressure oscillates and in electromagnetic waves the electric and magnetic fields vary. What is the equivalent quantity in the case of matter waves?
Or the is no physical quantity that corresponds to this?